# Comparing a buffer with a char does not work

Tags: c++

I'm making a function to print a whole line from a .txt file, until the end of the line is reached, however it doesn't seem to work, as it prints out the whole text (And yes, the Sleep() function actually works in the while)

```
void string_push(ifstream& file, string text, int time,int tm){
    char * buffer = new char [1];
    while (*buffer != '\n'){
        file.read(buffer,1);
        cout << *buffer;
        Sleep(tm);
    }
    Sleep(time);
}
```

I've tried inserting an 'y' at the end of the line, and replacing >'\n' with >'y', but it still doesn't work. What's wrong with it?

Comment: For one thing your loop logic is broken - you test `*buffer` before you've read anything into it. Another thing: you fail to check whether `file.read()` is successful.

Comment: For another, something wrong with `std::getline` ? And is `text` just sight-seeing or is it supposed to be involved in this somehow ?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://gist.github.com/sharth/9252aff3e6eea4e10cd9

Comment: Can't reproduce either.. Did you check whether opening the file was successful? You can just put your file var in an if for that; see an example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) and [running testcode including safety checks here](http://pastebin.com/kgTkEiAk)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are creating a array of 1 character from dynamic memory.  You should use a `char` variable:

```
void string_push(ifstream& file,  
                 string    text,
                 int       time,
                 int       tm)
{
    char b = '\0';
    while (b  != '\n')
    {
        file.read(&b,1);
        cout << b;
        Sleep(tm);
    }
    Sleep(time);
}
```

By using a temporary `char` variable, you eliminate memory fragmentation and the problems or memory management (allocation and deallocation).  Also, it eliminates the need to a call to the memory manager, thus making your program more efficient (the process can probably fit a character in a register and not use memory).

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  I thought the `read` method was passing by reference.

Comment: The problem is that the file still keeps reading, even though there clearly is a new line in the .txt

Comment: When you used the debugger, what was the character read at the end of the line?  Was it <CR>?  Was it <LF>? Was it <CR><LF>?

Comment: The character was '\n'. I just forgot I called the function multiple times. Thank you so much!

Comment: I've only used the buffer because I thought it was the best way to do this, I'm new into C++, so I'm still learning. Thank you so much. :)